# local storage prevent page reload

Tags: jquery, local-storage

i want to add a row when clicking save button of the form, it is happening, but then the page refresh itself(why?) and the new row dissapears. how to prevent it?

```
<button id="saveBtn">Save</button>

$("#saveBtn").click(function(){
    add();
});

function add() {
    var book = {};
    $('form [name]').each(function(){
        book[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    bookList.push(book);
    console.log(bookList);
    localStorage.setItem('bookList', JSON.stringify(bookList));
    showBooks();

}

function showBooks(){
    for (var i=0; i < bookList.length; i++){
        $("#tblData tbody").append("<tr>"+
                                     "  <td>"+bookList[i].author+"</td>" +
                                     "  <td>"+bookList[i].title+"</td>" +
                                     "</tr>");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your button event like this. when a click performed a postback also performed. By calling `event.preventDefault()` you can prevent this postback

```
$("#saveBtn").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
    add();
});
```